# Filter the value of dict with tuple key in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a very large dictionary like where the key is a tuple. Here is an example:

```
dic = {('A', 'B'): 1,
       ('A', 'C'): 2,
       ('B', 'C'): 3}
```

I am trying to filter the values of dict by only one element of the key. Here is what I am doing:

```
my_list = []

for k, v in dic.items():
    if "A" in k:
        my_list.append(v)

print(my_list)
[1, 2]
```

I am wondering is there a better way to perform this without looping through?

Comment: "I am wondering is there a better way to perform this without looping through?" Nope, this is the most efficient algorithm to solve your problem. Assuming by "better" you mean "more efficient" rather than "more idiomatic python".

Comment: I think given that storage structure that's the best you can do - if you're doing this search only once. You can express the code slightly more concisely if desired with a comprehension, but that won't help with performance. If you're searching repeatedly it might be worthwhile to consider indexing - eg build a map of the elements of the keys to the keys that contain them, either immediately prior to searching or as you establish the master data structure. But that's counterproductive for a single search.

Comment: (Also more memory intense, in case your data is large enough that that's a factor.)

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Thanks for the response. Yes the problem is that I have to search it repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

More pythonic for me:

```py
dic = {('A', 'B'): 1,
       ('A', 'C'): 2,
       ('B', 'C'): 3}
dic = [el[1] for el in dic.items() if 'A' in el[0]]
print(dic)
# Returns [1, 2]
```

Or with tuple unpacking:

```py
dic = [v for k, v in dic.items() if 'A' in k]
```

Comment: A list comprehension is still a loop

Comment: I'd prefer tuple unpacking to explicit indexing: `[v for k, v in dic.items() if 'A' in k]`.

Comment: @chepner in this case it definitely looks more intuitive. I'll add it to my answer if you don't mind.

Comment: `key` and `value` might be better variable names, too, but I lean towards being terse :)

Comment: @chepner this example is synthetic; in real life, the names of variables have to be more descriptive anyway :)

Comment: IMO `k` and `v` are common enough in a dictionary context not to need a more explicit name. Just don't do what one person I worked with did and use 'l' and 'w' as unexplained variable names if you need the key/value pairs from more than one dict in a given context!

Comment: If you are feeling mean, `[k for v, k in dic.items() if 'A' in v]`...

Answer (score 2):

I would restructure your dictionary.

```
dic = {("A", "B"): 1, ("A", "C"): 2, ("B", "C"): 3}
```

This is pretty much the same as:

```
better_dictionary = {"A": [1,2], "B": [1,3], "C": [2,3]}
```

Here is some code:

```
dic = {("A", "B"): 1, ("A", "C"): 2, ("B", "C"): 3}
better_dictionary = {}

# (one time) init better dict: O(n) -- with n being the number of tuples
for k, v in dic.items():
    for i in k:
        if i in better_dictionary:
            better_dictionary[i].append(v)
        else:
            better_dictionary[i] = [v]

my_list = better_dictionary["A"] # get values: O(1)
print(my_list)
# [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

With the information that you're searching repeatedly, this can be improved. Basically, you want to avoid traversing the entire data structure repeatedly. As long as memory permits, you can precalculate either a map from elements of the keys to a set of the matching keys or just to the values themselves.

```
from collections import defaultdict
index = defaultdict(set)
for k in dic:
    for element in k:
        index[element].add(k)
```

Then something like:

```
my_list = [dic[k] for k in index["A"]]
```

This might still underperform if you're just doing a couple of searches, since building the index is more expensive than one single search. You'd want to profile to determine that.

There are variations possible on this - for instance you can maintain the index as a parallel structure to the dict itself, modifying it as you add and delete elements. That's more complex but means you distribute the cost of computing the index. And don't have to do it more than once unless something goes wrong. But this is one basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension suggested by @Yevgeniy Kosmak is the most Pythonic way imo. However, if you don't want an explicit loop, then you could use `filter` and `zip` (which is pretty ugly imo):

```
list(zip(*filter(lambda x: 'A' in x[0], dic.items())))[1]
```

Here, with `filter`, we create an iterable of 2-tuples where the first elements are keys with `A` in it and the second elements are values of `dic`.

Then we unpack this iterable and use `zip` to create an iterable of tuples (we want the second element).

Output:

```
(1, 2)
```

If you need to do this multiple times, it's maybe a better idea to create another dictionary where keys are the first elements of the keys in `dic` and values are list of values in `dic` whose key's first elements match. That's suggested by @luku. Another way to do the same job is to use `dict.setdefault` method to traverse `dic` and append to values:

```
out = {}
for (k,_),v in dic.items():
    out.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
```

Then you can do:

```
>> print(out['A'])
[1, 2]
```